# Object property has different many string values

Tags: string, object, properties, key-value

I have objects, that has different properties, one of them is programingLanguage. So, with the function, I want to check if the object property - programmingLanguage has a value of "Java". if it has it returns true, if it doesn't it returns no data available. Here is the code below of my function.

I am stuck in the case when in object programmingLanguage property has a string value like this "C, Java", in this case, I also want to return true, when one of them is Java, but with my function, it returns no data available.

The problem is, I do not know how to check when there is 2 string values for the property if one of them matches to "Java"

```
function hasExamplesInJava(books) {
  if (books.programmingLanguage === "Java") {
    return true;
  } else if (books.programmingLanguage !== "Java") {
    return "No data available";
  }
}



{
  title: "Algorithms",
  author: ["Robert Sedgewick", "Kevin Wayne"],
  programmingLanguage: "Java",
}

{
  title: "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs",
  author: ["Harold Abelson", "Gerald Jay Sussman", "Julie Sussman (Contributor)"],
  programmingLanguage: "JavaScript",
}

{    
  title: "Operating System Concepts",
  author: ["Abraham Silberschatz", "Peter B. Galvin", "Greg Gagne"],
  programmingLanguage: "C, Java",
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you check out `includes()` method. If structure of `programmingLanguage` string is always comma separated values, I would suggest that you split it by comma and then check that array contains Java. Right now, you can change condition like this: `if (books.programmingLanguage.includes("Java"))`, but then it will be problem if, for example, word JavaScript appears because function will return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasExamplesInJava(books) { 
 if (books.programmingLanguage.includes("Java")) {
      return true;
 } else {
      return "No data available";
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is not to check if entire string is equal to "Java" but to check if string contains (or maybe better to say, includes) substring "Java". You can do it in a few different ways, so let's play a little.

1. First, you can check if entire string includes word "Java". Problem
   with that approach is that if string includes words that have "Java"
   in them, like "Javascript" for example, your function will return
   `true`. That's probably not what you want. That's shown with
   function `stringIncludesJava` in snippet.
2. Second, if languages in value of property `programmingLanguage` are
   always separated by comma, you can make array from them by splitting
   value with comma and getting array of languages. After that, check
   if array includes word "Java". That's shown with function
   `stringIncludesJavaWithSplit` in snippet.
3. Third, you can check if property includes "Java" using regex. If you
   are not familiar with regex, check it out, it can be really helpful
   when searching for words or phrases in text. That's shown with
   function `stringIncludesJavaWithRegex` in snippet.

By the way, it's not really good for functions to return different types of values as you did by returning boolean or string. It's better to return one type (in your example, return boolean and after function call check if boolean is true or false and go on from there). Also, it's often good to perform case-insensitive check unless you have need not to.

```js
let books = [
  {
    title: "Algorithms",
    author: ["Robert Sedgewick", "Kevin Wayne"],
    programmingLanguage: "Java",
  },
  {
    title: "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs",
    author: ["Harold Abelson", "Gerald Jay Sussman", "Julie Sussman (Contributor)"],
    programmingLanguage: "JavaScript",
  },
  {    
    title: "Operating System Concepts",
    author: ["Abraham Silberschatz", "Peter B. Galvin", "Greg Gagne"],
    programmingLanguage: "C, Java",
  }
]

function stringIncludesJava(book) {
  if (book.programmingLanguage.toLowerCase().includes("java"))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

function stringIncludesJavaWithSplit(book) {
  let languages = book.programmingLanguage.split(',').map(lang => lang.trim().toLowerCase());
  if (languages.includes("java"))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

function stringIncludesJavaWithRegex(book) {
  const regex = /\bjava\b/i;
  
  if (regex.test(book.programmingLanguage.toLowerCase()))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

for (let book of books) {
  console.log(`${book.programmingLanguage} -> ${stringIncludesJava(book)}`)
}

console.log("----------------")

for (let book of books) {
  console.log(`${book.programmingLanguage} -> ${stringIncludesJavaWithSplit(book)}`)
}

console.log("----------------")

for (let book of books) {
  console.log(`${book.programmingLanguage} -> ${stringIncludesJavaWithRegex(book)}`)
}
```